# pandas concating two default-indexed dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have data like (simplified for the sake of example):

```
list = [
    {
     age: 1234,
     val: 0.5,
     val2: 0.2
    },
    {
     age: 1234,
     val: 0.2,
     val2: 0.8
    },
]
```

I create pandas dataframe by `frame = pandas.DataFrame(list)` and it creates unnamed index from 0 to len(list) - 1.
Frame looks like:

```
     age  val  val2
0    1234 0.5  0.2
1    1234 0.2  0.8
```

Then I save it to csv by `frame.to_csv('file.csv')` - it goes ok.
But then, I want to create another frame exactly like this, load previous frame from csv file and add them together, so new data comes after old. I don't care about the index too, preferably it could go from 0 to new length with added data.
I tried doing it by `pd.concat([old_frame, new_frame], ignore_index=True)` but final data has now 2 columns with index values like this:

```
           age  val  val2
0     0    1234 0.5  0.2
1     1    1234 0.2  0.8
```

How to properly concat the frames without creating additional index column each time?

Comment: Incidentally, don't use `list` as a variable name to *store* a list. Doing so, overwrites its [`built-in functionality`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). E.g. use `my_list` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this part of code `frame.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)`

This is how it will look

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [
    {
     "age": 1234,
     "val": 0.5,
     "val2": 0.2
    },
    {
     "age": 1234,
     "val": 0.2,
     "val2": 0.8
    },
]

frame = pd.DataFrame(list)
frame.to_csv('file.csv', index=False) # <- change here


old_frame = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
new_frame = pd.DataFrame(list)



combined_frame = pd.concat([old_frame, new_frame], ignore_index=True)
```

The result will be:

```
age  val  val2
0  1234  0.5   0.2
1  1234  0.2   0.8
2  1234  0.5   0.2
3  1234  0.2   0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use **index=None** option. try this:

```
frame.to_csv('file.csv',index=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

To do this just use the `index=None` keyword argument in the `.to_csv` function like such:

```py
.to_csv('foo.csv',index=None)
```